# Why does CURTIME()) work but NOW() doesn't when I use the MYSQL INSERT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me out here! That's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `revolut_accounts`

 `account_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL ,
 `name`       varchar(45) NOT NULL ,
 `createDate` timestamp NOT NULL ,
 `updateDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE NOW(),
PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`)
);
```

When I try to Insert data with **now()** function I get an error:

```
INSERT INTO revolut_accounts (account_id, name, createDate) VALUES ('test', 'Main British Pounds', NOW());
```

However, when I do the same with **CURTIME())** it works:

```
INSERT INTO revolut_accounts (account_id, name, createDate) VALUES ('test', 'Main British Pounds', CURTIME());
```

Please tell my Why???

Comment: You shared table structure of accounts but trying to insert data into revolut_accounts. Please check. I tried both your queries for accounts table and those are just working fine.

Comment: I would agree, more than likely the revolut_accounts->createDate is a TIME and not TIMESTAMP

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur I wanted to remove the term "revolut" in this post here, but obviously forgot to remove it in the insert statement as well. That wasn't the mistake when I tried it on the server. I use a google SQL cloud database with  MySQL 8.0 installed.

Comment: @Forbs no I used for this table timestamp.

Comment: Try changing the TIMESTAMP to a DATETIME, Timestamps are usually associated with ON INSERT or ON UPDATE